# How frequently does the /workingWith contact list update in Office 365 Graph API?

Tags: office365, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

I would like to cache the results of the workingWith request:
    `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/workingWith`

But I want to make sure the data will not be stale. In order to decide upon how frequently to poll against this endpoint, I'd like to know how frequently the data is updated on the server.

There is nothing in the online documentation regarding this. Is anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This API refreshes based on user activity. We do not recommend caching its data if what you want to get the is the current and contextual list of the user's relevant people. Also we are folding this API into /people API so I recommend that you look into using the People API instead

Comment: Thanks for the information, I'll take a look at the people API